# React Highchart JS xAxis Labels

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to visualize data via a websocket.
The incoming data has the format:

[image]

Highcharts still shows the xAxis as a numerical value between 0 and 100.
How can i get there the created_time from the dataPoint Object?

I tried the xAxis Formatter, but formatting this numerical Value doesnt give me a datetime object or a datetime string. I pass the datapoint object as a prop and therefore i also tried accessing this.props.dataPoint.created_time,
but unfortunately this.props.dataPoint is in the beginning undefined, when i start the App.

This is the code for the chart component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import { SensorData } from './types';
import { slidingTimeWindowSec } from './utils';

// noinspection TsLint
const Boost = require('highcharts/modules/boost');
Boost(Highcharts); // WebGL-backed rendering (https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/higcharts-boost-module/)

type Props = {
    readonly dataPoint: SensorData
}

class HighchartsTimeSeries extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

    private readonly renderToId = 'highcharts-container'
    private chart: Highcharts.Chart | undefined

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.chart = (Highcharts as any).chart({
            title: {
                text: 'Live Data via WebSocket'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    step: 2,
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 80
            },
            series: [{
                type: "area",
                name: 'Temperatur C',
                data: this.props.dataPoint
            }],
            chart:{
                renderTo: this.renderToId
            }
        })
        requestAnimationFrame(this.redrawChart)
    }

    public componentDidUpdate() {
        // @ts-ignore
        const series = this.chart.series[0];
        const firstPoint = series.data[0];
        const shouldShift = series.data[0] ? firstPoint.x < Date.now() - slidingTimeWindowSec * 1000 : false;
        series.addPoint([this.props.dataPoint.created_time, this.props.dataPoint.temperature], false, shouldShift, false);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div id={this.renderToId}/>
        );
    }

    private redrawChart = () => {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.chart.redraw(false);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.redrawChart);
    }

}

export default HighchartsTimeSeries;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse your data format before loading it into the chart. Something like this:

```
let data = [{
    created_time: "2020-10-18T11:53:07.948019+02:00",
    humidity: 74.09,
    id: 7103,
    light: 349.16,
    occupancy: true,
    people_count: 225,
    temperature: 19.200
}];

data.forEach(d => {
    d.x = Date.parse(d.created_time);
    d.y = d.temperature
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y9avzLsq/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse